# IE6 download dynamic excel blocked by firewall

Tags: excel, firewall, internet-explorer-6

I've created a tool that allows the client to dynamicly create a excel document based on the selected products. For this functionality I used PHPExcell. I've tested it on almost every browser and it's working fine (even in IE6).

The problem starts with the clients network, its a big company so they can't choose what browser they're using and they're stucked with IE6. Everything works fine except the excel download. After the generation a popup shows what they want to do (save/open) but when they press one of them a error occurs (could not acces file or file path could not be found or something like that). At the same time they get a warning from mcafee that a they're trying to open a unsave file.

When they try it on a http server it only happens once, when they go back to the page after the error everything works fine, even the excel generation.
But the error keeps coming on the https server, so they can't use it.

How to avoid / work around this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Are the clients accessing over an ssl link?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the workbook is being built in a temporary internet files folder and the system is refusing to let them copy an open temp file to some other location on their system (as it should). You should try to arrange for something that will ask for the download location before hand and dynamically build the file from there.

Comment: You got a point there, but then its strange that an image output (dynamicly created from flash) can be saved and opened, without any problems. Maybe it has something to do with IE6 not supporting newer versions of office or something like that?

Comment: Well the entire operating system recognizes that Excel documents can contain VBA code capable of doing absolutely anything to the system - it's the equivalent of opening an executable file. For that reason, it is probably treated more strictly than images and other harmless files. I guarantee that this isn't an IE6 problem - this will be an operating system enforced rule. Try creating an xlsx document (instead of macro enabled formats), and see if it's any different. If that fails, try CSV, just to see.